# Let git ask for passphrase in separate window instead of terminal

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit

I have configured my `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
host myserver_myuser
    user myuser
    hostname myserver
    port 1234
    identityfile ~/.ssh/myserver.private
```

When executing a remote Git command, Git always asks me for my private key's passphrase:

```
$ git ls-remote myserver_myuser:/path/to/repository
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/myserver.private':
```

When launching this Git command from an application which does not have a terminal, this causes troubles, because Git still asks for the passphrase on an invisible terminal. I've tried to tell msysgit to use `git-gui--askpass`, but it still asks for the passphrase on command line:

```
$ export SSH_ASKPASS=/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
$ git ls-remote myserver_myuser:/path/to/repository
Enter passphrase for key '~/.ssh/myserver.private':
```

How I can convince msysgit to use `git-gui--askpass` to ask for the passphrase?

Comment: You should really consider using ssh-agent...

Comment: Could you please consider to write an answer how to use ssh-agent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Github has some msysgit + ssh-agent instructions here: http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/